# COUNTIF with function in criterion

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'd like to count all cells in a range where a given function evaluates to TRUE. The documentation for [`COUNTIF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480) & [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) show text-matching and evaluation of `=`,`<>`,`<`,`>`, but nothing more sophisticated.

Here's an example with the function `ISDATE` (could be any TRUE/FALSE function) [as a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UDyMI-QpiRDr6TvIe6WtkwZCXPQGatSCbzYk-HARlnc/edit#gid=0) or as a table:

|  | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7/28/2021 | <- is a date |
| 2 | 12/7/1941 | <- is a date |
| 3 | =TODAY() | <- is a date |
| 4 | foobar | <- is not a date |
| 5 |  | <- is not a date |
| 6 | =COUNTIF(A1:A5, "=ISDATE()") | <- should evaluate to 3 |

Is something like that possible?

Comment: I know I could accomplish this with an `ISDATE` helper column. I'd like to understand what's possible within the `COUNTIF` condition specifically. (In the real spreadsheet in question, I don't have permissions to add a column.)

Comment: It's not possible seeing as that goes against the syntax for criterion https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480?hl=en. "criterion must be a string"

Answer (score 0):

Change `=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "=ISDATE()")` to `=COUNTIF(B1:B5, TRUE)`

This will count how many `ISDATE` function calls in column B have evaluated to TRUE. Instead of what you were doing which was counting how many times the string `=ISDATE()` appears in the first 5 cells of column A.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically interested in the form of the `COUNTIF` condition argument.

Answer (score -2):

- Column B `=ISDATE(A1)`
- B6 `=COUNTIF(B1:B5,TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm specifically interested in the form of the `COUNTIF` condition argument.